# C# How can I "save" a specific copy of a randomly generated Class object?

Tags: c#, class, object, save

I am making a battleship game in console and I would like to implement a replay-system, where I could rewatch games. For this I use StreamWriter to record the player's moves, and in a different loop, a StreamReader uses these to 'replay' the game on screen. However, the position of the ships is not the same, because it is generated when a new game is started. 
The NEWGAME loop is the same as the REPLAY, but in the replay the comp automatically makes the moves via the streamreader, however, the map is different because it is always randomly generated.
My question is that how can I save an exact copy of a 'map' that is in this situation a class?
Thanks in advance! If you have any questions I can answer.

```
switch (x)
        {
            case "newgame":
        Mezo Játékos2Hajói= new Mezo();
        Mezo Játékos1AmitLát = new Mezo();
        Mezo Játékos1Hajói = new Mezo();
        Mezo Játékos2AmitLát = new Mezo();
....
```

This generates the field for the new game, then come the rest, player attacks etc.

The replay case works the same as a new game, but the attacks are inserted by the computer from a streamreader.

```
        case "replay":
        Mezo Játékos2VHajói= new Mezo();
        Mezo Játékos1VAmitLát = new Mezo();
        Mezo Játékos1VHajói = new Mezo();
        Mezo Játékos2VAmitLát = new Mezo();
```

The problem is here. This case generates a new for itself, because it wouldn't work, but here I would like to use the one used in newgame".

Comment: I'll just add a code snippet so you guys can better understand, I can't really explain it by heart. :)

Comment: Use a seed for your PRNG and take note of it. When you load/replay a game use your PRNG with that seed to re-generate the level, it will be identical. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww.aspx

Comment: I've dug into this but just can't understand it clearly. This battleship thing is university material and we just haven't learned seeds or anything like that.

Comment: You have 2 options to you, either you save the level map or the seed number. All in all you are probably using `Random` class to generate the map so you are better off simply saving the seed rather than the full level map. A seed for instance is very helpful while debugging because it will produce the same sequence.

Comment: I'd just rather save the map with the ships on it as they are. Is there any way to easily do that? I have a method for the ships being placed on the map. If I could save an instance of that and reuse it, that'd be great.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the kind of thing that the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) is great for. Here's a simplified version of something you could do:

```
interface ICommand { void Execute(); }

class PlaceShip : ICommand
{
    int x;
    int y;
    Ship ship;

    public PlaceShip(int x, int y, Ship ship)
    {
        // Initialize fields
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        // Place the ship
    }
}

class Fire : ICommand
{
    int x;
    int y;
    Player player;

    public Fire(int x, int y, Player player)
    {
        // Initialize fields
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        // Try to hit enemy
    }
}
```

Then you can keep a history of `ICommand` objects which you can replay easily by just iterating through the list again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a [XMLSerialize](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/csharp/xmlserializer-example.htm) to export a the whole class to a Structured XMl automatically. It's kind of a way to make a full copy of the object in XML.